# Add support for legacy behavior in ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm migrating an application based on .net framework to .net core.
There's a web application which hosts user provided templates which are cshtml files, like this:

/Template/A.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <a href="@Href("B.cshtml")">link</a></body>
</html>
```

This should be used inside the new application without modification. Because the files reference each other, I cannot change the urls. The routes matched the filenames before:

| Route | Page |
| --- | --- |
| /Template/A.cshtml | /Template/A.cshtml |
| /Template/B.cshtml | /Template/B.cshtml |

The templates can be added after compilation. So runtime compilation must be supported (AddRazorRuntimeCompilation).

I already mapped the static files:

```
// Server static files
// -- from wwwroot
app.UseStaticFiles();
// -- from Templates
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Templates")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Templates")
});

app.UseRouting();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

- Can razor pages be configured to support routes like
  "Template/A.cshtml"?
- The legacy templates do not contain a "@page"
  directive. Is it possible to pretend it is there?

**Update**

It is possible to add some preprocessing to the files. Thus the @page directive can be added to the cshtml files in some automated processing step.

More difficult is to get the routes right. This should be possible by searching the files on disk and adding some endpoints. Then the actions must be created for each file. That's where [runtime compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) comes into play.

```
/* Pseudocode */
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    foreach (var filename in Directory.GetFiles(...)) {
        var action = GetPageAction(filename);
        endpoints.MapSomething(filename, action);
    }
}
```

I don't like to search the files in Startup class. There has to be some logic for that in Razor Pages. So I'd like to know how to configure that.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the old asp.net CSHTML page, it will not work inside the new Razor page.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Do refer to the missing "@page" directive? Well, I could patch the files with that. It should be easy to automate that.

Comment: Since the razor page's cshtml will be different , it will contain its model class and it need specific rule. I suggest you could try to create a new page inside the razor page and copy the codes from old cshtml inside it.